# Bundle install won't install gem locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to install a specific branch of a repo.

```
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on',
    :github => 'bradly/acts-as-taggable-on',
    :branch => 'allow_reseting_of_tag_lists_and_cached_tag_lists'
```

When I run `bundle install`, I get:

```
Using acts-as-taggable-on (3.0.1) from git://github.com/bradly/acts-as-taggable-on.git (at allow_reseting_of_tag_lists_and_cached_tag_lists)
```

However, I can't view the gem's repo locally. When I install the gem without the `:github` and `:branch` options, it installs fine and I can view the repo.

Comment: If I remember correctly `bundler` installs gems in your case in a different path. Try print `bundle show acts-as-taggable-on` and you should see where bundler installed the gem

Comment: It seems it's installed in a different path than other gems. How do I change it?

Comment: why would you like to change it? `bundler` handles this correctly. Everything should work if you run commands like `bundle exec ...` (for example `bundle exec rail s`)

Comment: This is a forked version of a gem. Certain API's that should be public in the forked version are not available within my app, so I think it's installed incorrectly.

Comment: if you would like to have own path for gem you can clone it manually (`git clone ...`) and then set option `path` in `Gemfile` `gem 'my_gem', path: path_to_gem`. see [this doc](http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's normal for Bundler to install git gems in a different location than gems installed from a `.gem` file. Git gems are a Bundler-specific extension, handled very differently from gem files, so they need to be managed in a different location on the filesystem.

As long as you use `bundle exec` to run your commands, everything should work fine.